# Why is a PNG image downloaded by reqwest corrupt?

Tags: rust, async-await, http-get, reqwest

I am following the code mentioned in Rust Cookbook at https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/clients/download.html to download a file in async way by HTTP GET request.

My code is as follows:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {

    let object_path = "logos/rust-logo-512x512.png";
    let target = format!("https://www.rust-lang.org/{}", object_path);  
    let response = reqwest::get(&target).await?;

    let mut dest = {
    
        let fname = response
            .url()
            .path_segments()
            .and_then(|segments| segments.last())
            .and_then(|name| if name.is_empty() { None } else { Some(name) })
            .unwrap_or("tmp.bin");
            
            
        println!("file to download: '{}'", fname);

        let object_prefix = &object_path[..object_path.rfind('/').unwrap()];
        let object_name = &object_path[object_path.rfind('/').unwrap()+1..];
        let output_dir = format!("{}/{}", env::current_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string(), object_prefix);
        fs::create_dir_all(output_dir.clone())?;

        println!("will be located under: '{}'", output_dir.clone());
                
        let output_fname = format!("{}/{}", output_dir, object_name);
        println!("Creating the file {}", output_fname);
        
        File::create(output_fname)?
        
    };
    let content =  response.text().await?;
    copy(&mut content.as_bytes(), &mut dest)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

It creates the directories & downloads the file.
However, when I open the file, it displays corrupt file error
I have tried to use some other URL also, but the corrupt file issue is still there

Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: You're downloading the response as text, so naturally it won't work because PNG files are binary.

Comment: use [`bytes`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes) instead of `text`

Comment: I tried ```let content =  response.bytes().await?;
 copy(&mut content, &mut dest)?;``` but it gives error ``` copy(&mut content, &mut dest)?;    the trait std::io::Read is not implemented for bytes::bytes::Bytes
```

Comment: @test, use [`io::Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using [`bytes`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.bytes) and [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) work too, and it is simpler:

```rust
let mut content =  Cursor::new(response.bytes().await?);
copy(&mut content, &mut dest)?;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing

```
let content =  response.text().await?;
copy(&mut content.as_bytes(), &mut dest)?;
```

by

```
let content =  response.bytes().await?;
    
let mut pos = 0;
while pos < content.len() {
    let bytes_written = dest.write(&content[pos..])?;
    pos += bytes_written;
}
```

worked! :)

Please reply if this code is inefficient
Thanks to all for help.

Comment: Simpler to use [`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all): `dest.write_all (&content)?;` instead of doing the loop by hand.